# Windows Azure Automation

Tags: azure, automation, cloud

I'm trying to deploy a runbook in Windows azure automation but I can't run the script to turn on or turn off my VM because I can't authenticate with the machine.  Can someone tell me the correct way to use the azure account to authenticate the script?

Another question... on the internet I find some way using `.pfx` certificate but I'm not sure if I should use the certificate from my local machine or from my VM?

Below I post my current script:

```
workflow TurnOnServer{
   inlineScript {
      Select-AzureSubscription - SubscriptionName 'My Subscription'
      Get-AzureVM -ServiceName ServerName
      Stop-AzureVM -Name ServerName -ServiceName ServiceName
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to authenticate with Azure from your runbook. Either generate a [self-signed  certificate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/04/step-by-step-getting-started-with-windows-azure-automation.aspx), upload it to Azure as a management certificate, then reference it as an asset to authenticate. Or, you can now authenticate using [Azure Active Directory](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to authenticate before Selecting your subscription.
Add this in the beginning of the InlineScript

```
$username = "your username"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" –asplaintext –force 
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
```

and then give Select-AzureSubscription cmdlet.

Another good practice is to put the user name and password in your automation assets.

1. Open your automation account in azure portal
2. go to Assets and then choose Add Settings
3. Choose Add-Credential
4. Give your username and password and give a name for this credential say "MyCred"
5. Instead of the four lines I gave above give this.

   ```
   $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential –Name ‘MyCred’
   Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
   ```